# Visual Studio: iOS Simulator gone as of today

Tags: ios, visual-studio

The list of the simulators of iOS in visual studio is empty.

In Xcode, they are all still listed.
I think today was the rollout of iOS 15 for the new iPhone 13.
Just starting the simulator at least lets me still start the newest iPhone but I dont think that is compatible with visual studio yet.

So it seems like the rollout overwrote all simulators only leaving me with the iPhone 13. So no simulator appears in my list anymore.

I tried:

- removing bin and obj folder.
- Unloading and reloading iOS project.
- restarting VS
- restarting MAC
- checking xCODE simulators (all there)
- downloading ios 14 in xCode

Anyone else having this issue? Please report.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This has happend because the system automaatically updated to ios 15 in the background. this wasnt support by visual studio and a downgrade is only hard to achieve. however, this thread deals with it there are multiple options.

downloading the beta xamarin.ios xamarin.ios-14.20.0.27.pkg worked for me:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12778